# Response from JUnit is different then normal response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Current tech stack:

- Spring Boot 2.3.2
- JUnit5
- MockMvc

In my application.properties, I have included:

```
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

So all responses get `";charset=UTF-8"` appended. This works as expected in Swagger, Fiddler, real world.

I built my unit test as:

```
    String result = mockMvc().perform(get("/customers")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_xxx)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorization()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_xxx_UTF8))
            .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                    .getContentAsString();

    List<CustomerDto> customers = this.objectMapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<List<CustomerDto>>(){});
```

Note that I have set expected contentType as `MediaType.APPLICATION_xxx_UTF8` which is `MediaType.APPLICATION_xxx` with the `";charset=UTF-8"` appended.

However, the response is coming back as just `MediaType.APPLICATION_xxx`.

I'm new to junit and mockmvc, but I'm assuming mockmvc isn't really sending an http request? So its not going through the servlet to append the charset?

How can I get it to append the charset? I know I can just accept the non-UTF8 type, but I'm wanting to test what the real world will get.

EDIT: Mockmvc is created as:

```
public ControllerTestsBase(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                           FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain) {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
        .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Show how you're acquiring your `mockMvc` instance.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- updated post.

Comment: Try using `@Autowired MockMvc` and see if if works there.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- nope, tried grabbing it that way when I started. it's not a bean.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- using Arghya Sadhu answer with the filter, I'm doing if (!contentType.endsWith(MediaType.CHARSET_UTF8))
     response.setContentType(contentType + ";" + MediaType.CHARSET_UTF8); and its appending it... not sure if that is a good way to do it though... but it does append it...

Comment: This is an indication of the underlying problem: _make_ `@Autowired MockMvc` work. (Usually, the problem is that you aren't using `@SpringBootTest`.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have the SpringBootTest annotation and I added a MockMvc object to the constructor and it fails saying no bean is available. Do I need a certain dependency for that?

Comment: It's really hard to debug a no-code description. Post your entire test class (with just a single test method included). (Note that it's possible that you'll need to use field injection with MockMvc; this is mostly-not-a-problem inside test cases.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- ahh... also needed the AutoConfigureMockMvc... now I get an autowired mockMvc, but it still doesn't append the charset.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it did do the security filter though...

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- what I posted above is it... I'm using the autowired mockmvc now and that is my one test... with the autowired one, I can't add a filter though cuz its already built.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`; I couldn't remember offhand whether the default `@SpringBootTest` activated it or it needed additional setting. Note that MockMvc is _extremely_ easy to configure in a way that is different from your actual application, which is why I recommend against ever using the builders and instead getting an injected object. Please still post your entire test class, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219235/discussion-between-chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-and-sledgehammer).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I obsessed over this some more today...I see what the problem is lol... if you do the filter trick below (and setCharacterEncoding has to be called AFTER doFilter or the if statements inside will fail), it DOES infact update the response headers correctly. If you look at MockHttpServletRequest::updateContentTypeHeader() you'll see that it updates this.headers only. It doesn't update this.contentType. So when you call .contentType() in the unit test, it's getting the original, unaltered one.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- looks like they fixed it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25536#issuecomment-671310109

Comment: Nicely done. I'll note that it's often a good idea to include a link to this SO question in your GH ticket so that people who find one can cross-reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set character encoding as below in `MockMvcBuilders`

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
        .addFilter((request, response, chain) -> {
          response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // this is crucial
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }, "/*")
        .build();
  }
```

Alternatively you can override `WebMvcConfigurer` as below

```
Configuration
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream()
            .filter(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(converter -> ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).setDefaultCharset(UTF_8));
    }
```

Comment: response.setCharacterEncoding() doesn't append the ;charset=UTF8 to the response type.

Comment: Okay..can you try the alternative one

Comment: This completely sidesteps what OP is intending to test, though